# Get the content of a task in Asana when user create it

Tags: task, crm, asana

When a user of my CRM **created a task** in his Asana account, I want to get **the content** of this task to put on my CRM in his account. How can I do that? I read the Asana API doc but I can't find what I search.

Comment: Can you specify the context a bit more? Do you have the ID of the task? What content do you want, the title, notes, comments, due date? Do you have the user's API key, or an API key for a different user? What kind of language are you calling from, is this a background process or a web application or what?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without further details, but you may want `GET /tasks/:id`, which returns the details of a task. See https://asana.com/developers/api-reference/tasks for more information on which fields that contains, the relevant call is under "Showing a specific task".